# How do I downgrade Go from 1.10 to 1.9?

Tags: debugging, go, visual-studio-code, downgrade

I have a problem with debugging in Go 1.10 in vscode using delve on Mac.
I read [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-5446) that the workaround is to downgrade to Go 1.9.
Since I am new at Go, but have lots of stuff already installed, how do I do this cleanly?

Comment: Well, I just downloaded 1.9.5 darwin installer from [golang.org](https://golang.org/project/) and it uninstalled 1.10 and now the debugger works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The same way you upgrade. That is, remove the existing version, then install the new version. Although "downgrade" isn't explicitly stated on the official docs, it [does explain how to do it](https://golang.org/doc/install#install).

Answer (score 3):

First remove go from the system

- `sudo snap remove go`

Then install particular version of go

- `sudo snap install --classic --channel=1.14/stable go`

Answer (score 2):

To downgrade Go on MacOS, for instance from `go@1.20` to `go@1.19`:

```
$ brew unlink go@1.20
$ brew install go@1.19
$ brew link go@1.19
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you need to downgrade Go in order to reenable the debugging. I had the same problem on a Mac(10.13) and the problem seems to be XCode.

[Here](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/issues/1015#issuecomment-377654359) I've found the solution for fixing the debugging problem.

You should delete the current XCode Command Line Tools binary:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and install an older XCode Command Line Tools (for me it's working with 9.2) using one of the following links:

- [XCode 9.2 for macOS 10.13](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg)
- [XCode 9.2 for macOS 10.12](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to upgrade or downgrade Go on Ubuntu is to download required version from [here](https://golang.org/dl/). Here you could have all stable and releases, along with archived versions.

after downloading you selected version you can follow further steps, i will suggest you to download tar.gz format for ubuntu machine:

1. first of all fully remove the older version from your local by doing this

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go /usr/local/gocache`

this will remove all the local go code base but wait something more we have to do to remove fully from local, i was missing this step and it took so much time until I understood what i am missing so here is the purge stuff to remove from list

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge golang
> ```

or

> ```
> sudo apt remove golang-go
> ```

2. Now install / extract your downloaded version of go inside /usr/local/go, by hitting terminal with this

> `tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.10.8.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

3. after doing all above stuff , don't forget or check to `GOROOT` variable value you can check the value by `go env` if not set then `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go`
4. Better to test a small go program to make sure. write this inside `/home/yourusername/go/test.php` if you haven't changed set `GOPATH` value:

> ```
> package main
>
> import "fmt"
>
> func main() {
>     fmt.Println("hello world")
> }
> ```

5. run this by `go run test.go`

i hope it works for you!!

Answer (score -4):

I use my own [fork](https://github.com/e-nikolov/gvm) of [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) to easily switch between go versions. The original gvm is fairly old and keeps a different gopath per go version which I found annoying and removed in my fork.

So after setting up gvm, you can do

```
gvm install go1.9.5 -B
gvm use go1.9.5 --default
```

The -B flag installs go from a binary release. If you don't add it, it will try to compile it from sources, which requires a bit more setup.